# vertical centering in gwt

Tags: html, css, gwt

how to vertical centering in gwt by using vertical panel.. or pls sugest me is there any way for doing vertical cetering

Answer (score 6):

If you want to directly use the `VerticalPanel` from code, you need to use the `setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE)`

You can also use the UiBinder approach

```
<g:VerticalPanel verticalAlignment='ALIGN_MIDDLE' horizontalAlignment='ALIGN_CENTER' width="100%" height="500px">
  <g:cell></g:cell>
</g:VerticalPanel>
```

Take a look to [DevGuideUiPanels](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html) for examples and documentation

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an example on how we did it with css (to implement a popup like behaviour).

If you google for it there are dozens of solutions on how to achieve vertical centering. This example worked for us, so no guarantee if it's of any help for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0 auto; 
        }

        .popup {
            border-color:#ff4f00;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:5px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            text-align: left;
        }

        #wrapper, #container {
            height: 150px;
            width: 550px;
        }

        #wrapper {
            bottom: 50%;
            right: 50%;
            position:
            absolute;
        }

        #container {
            left: 50%;
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
        }
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>vertical centering</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 965px; height: 515px;"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="popup" id="container">
            some content
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: check also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510690/how-can-i-vertically-center-an-element-with-gwt) out.